# How to get Foundation for Apps page template to work?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am trying to use any of these page templates located here [Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/page-templates.html)

Some of the template (navbar), but not the content. Basically when I try to navigate to some content nothing happens. I have added the route info to no avail, i.e. -

---

name: home

### url: /

When I create the basic starter project from here: [Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/getting-started.html), the project comes with .scss and a templates.js file, however the page templates just have a .css file.

I've looked through the documentation but haven't found anything showing how to use the page templates. Do I need to creata a .scss file and template.js file on my own and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

For use this templates you must follow this former instruction http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/getting-started.html

For short:

1. install foundation nodejs module
2. create app – insert your
3. put template to client folder